# Data not showing - Ember js - Rest Api

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So I've had a look around and can't really find a solid  answer.

I have a model for page and I have a route to get the data from an Api and the data comes though into the ember inspector but when I try to call it on the page it doesn't show.

https://github.com/stagfoo/ember-wip/blob/master/app/templates/page.hbs

I've tried {{title}},{{Title}} {{page.title}} nothing shows.

I've read I need a controller but I've seen examples without a controller do the same thing.

What an I missing?

https://github.com/stagfoo/ember-wip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try

```
{{model.title}}
```

Also, I don't understand what you are trying to do in your 'then(...)' at https://github.com/stagfoo/ember-wip/blob/master/app/routes/page.js.

Indeed, an Ember route exposes a model to templates via the value returned by its model hook. When calling an API, this value is a Promise that will be resolved after server response. Ember handles this Promise itself and the template will be dynamically updated.

So you do not have to call yourself 'then' unless you have to setup other data and need to wait the Promise resolution. Moreover, in this particular case, your 'then' implementation do nothing but accessing a value.

Do I miss something ?

Comment: using `{{model.title}}` would make sense because on the homepage i have `{{#each model as |page|}}` and then `{{page.title}}` but i tried it and it didn't work. Its really weird. thanks for explaining the "then", i thought it was similar to how you can use `renderTemplate()` but it doesn't matter at the moment. I removed the "then" and removed the `renderTemplate()` to simplify. [This is what i have tried](https://github.com/stagfoo/ember-wip/blob/master/app/templates/page.hbs) the loop works but nothing else :(

Comment: Is your server responding a non empty & valid JSON ? Do you see erros in console ?

Comment: I think that your template is OK but your request is not. First, you should not query, query is for multiple record. Use queryRecord for single record. Then you use filter: {name: params.slug}. This will lead to this request : http://you.host/pages?filter[name]=slug which is obviously not you API. try this.store.queryRecord('page', {slug: params.slug}

Comment: No errors in console. Data is returned in an each loop but not outside one. The data is coming through into the ember console under data with data matching tge model from the Json so every thing seems vaild. Is there like a binding in missing or something?

Comment: And your routes are not correct either. You cannot define a child route without parent. You should use this router : this.route('pages', function() {
    this.route('page', {path: ':slug'});
  }); then move page.js into pages/page.js in routes directory

Comment: The new url will be localhost:4200/pages/planning

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, I really appreciate it. So queryRecord works if i use an id but i want to use a slug.

if I use `this.store.queryRecord('page',  { filter: { name: params.slug } });` i get an error in console `while processing route: page Assertion Failed: You must include an 'id' for page in an object passed to 'push'` what id am i missing?

I tested that data `/https://wpapi-stagfoo.rhcloud.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages?filter[name]=planning` it returns the correct page info.

Comment: I had a look at the router, it is currently work as is or do you think it could cause data issues with the current route?

Comment: Ok, I did not see you were accessing your pages through '/' directly. But be carrefull to your URLs when you use the name as dynamic segment. I suggest you use slugs instead (that why slugs are there). Your data seem ok. You should debug your serialier. It should be customized / updated somewhere I guess

Comment: Ok Thanks so much for the help, I think i can tweak it from here. Im going to approve your answer and ill stop annoying you haha ^__^